Why are my POST requests with attached files extremely slow in production with SvelteKit?
I am developing a web application with SvelteKit as my frontend framework. During development, all requests behave normally. However, in production, POST requests that include an attached .xlsx file experience significant delays, sometimes taking over 10 minutes to complete.
Initially, I suspected the reverse proxy between the frontend and backend (introduced in production) was causing the issue. However, upon inspecting the request timing in the browser's developer tools, I noticed that the request is blocked for approximately 5 minutes, followed by a similar delay during the sending phase.
Here are the detailed timings for a POST request that uploads a 64 kB .xlsx file (translated from Spanish):

Blocking: 5.06 min
DNS Resolution: 0 ms
Connecting: 245 ms
TLS Configuration: 0 ms
Sending: 5.07 min
Waiting: -1 ms
Receiving: 4.34 s

Based on my research, I suspect this might be due to Mozilla's restrictions on concurrent connections to the same server. While it’s possible to adjust browser preferences, this is not a viable solution as I cannot expect my users to modify their browser settings.
Here is some context about the project:

The entire application is Dockerized.
The backend uses Django, and there is a reverse proxy between the frontend and backend.
The frontend is built with SvelteKit, using the Node adapter for deployment.
Currently, both the backend and frontend are hosted on the same machine, and the application is accessed over the LAN only (for now, it doesn't reach the internet due to ongoing security configurations).

In certain sections of the app, users are required to upload .xlsx files via a file input. If multiple files are needed, I dynamically generate forms using JavaScript and send them one by one, tracking the responses. This is when the excessive request times occur.
Here’s the relevant code for sending the POST requests:
async function requestAsyncTask() {
    for (let i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        forms[i].stage.status = 'pending';
        const form = new FormData();
        form.append('file', forms[i].file[0]);

        const response = await fetch(forms[i].query, {
            method: "POST",
            body: form
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            forms[i].stage.status = 'success';
        } else {
            forms[i].stage.status = 'error';
        }
    }
    ableToClose = true;
}

onMount(() => {
    requestAsyncTask();
});

Important Notes:
Even though the project is in production, it is currently used only within a local network (LAN). The problem persists even under these conditions.
I am hoping to eliminate the long blocking and sending times. While the underlying cause may relate to persistent connections held by the browser, I’m unsure how to address this.
I’ve read that the Connection header cannot be manually set in fetch requests. Is there a way to optimize or manage these connections properly?
Any guidance or suggestions are welcome. Let me know if more details are needed.

Do you have this problem only in FireFox, or also in other web browsers?

Wait, you have Sending: 5.07 min. And you send more of these requests than the web browser allows you to send at the same time, so the reason you have Blocking: 5.06 min is because the web browser is waiting for one of the earlier sent request to complete before it sends this one. So, the problem is that the server takes a long time to receive/handle the file.

@PeppeL-G I performed tests in chrome aswell, getting a similar stalled times, but much less sending times.

@PeppeL-G It also happens with the first requests. In my Chrome tests, the first request stalled for approximately 5 minutes, while the second one only took 0.26 ms. In Mozilla, everyone gets blocked for at least 5 minutes and then an additional 5 minutes for sending. The requests don’t reach the frontend server, as I can see from the logs. The server becomes aware of the requests and contacts the backend only after the stalling time. While the data processing takes longer than ideal, it’s negligible compared to the significant blocking/stalling time.
